# how to make my Alarm service run background?

Tags: android

i've had made my alarm service successfully but the problem is instead of app running in background the app restarts itself by self launching after few second so instead of relaunching i want my alarm service to run background only

here is my code

```
Intent alarm = new Intent(this.context, AlarmReceiver.class);
boolean alarmRunning = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, alarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

if(alarmRunning == false) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 1000, pendingIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to start a service in your Application class to run it always. If you do that, your service will be always running. Even though user terminates your app from task manager or force stop your app, it will start running again.

Create a Service

```
public class YourService extends Service {

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // do your jobs here
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
} }
```

Create an Application class and start your service:

```
public class App extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
}}
```

Don't forget add this in "application" tag of your AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:name=".App"
```

Comment: i found that this code bellow  is making to relaunch the app after certain time do you have any solution                                                                   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);